# Passing Bluetooth Socket between fragments

Tags: java, android

I am new at android studio and was wondering how I could pass a Bluetooth socket from one fragment to another. I saw a lot about activitys using the application class but am having problems implementing it into the code.

Comment: You can simply run the socket in your service and bind the service to whichever fragment you are currently in.

Comment: why on god's green earth would you want to pass around a socket

Comment: @SujithNiraikulathan can´t bind the service to the second fragment (have 3 fragments). Everything works fin in the first fragment, can´t find helpful documentation about this, not any working example. I have posted a question abouth this, and will offer bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your socket a **singleton** in that way you can using the same instance wherever you want do it.